# Impala - How to compare date time type 'mm dd yy 00:00AM'

Tags: sql, impala

In Impala, when I tried to compared the date, it will give wrong result.
For example:

```
select 'Nov 23 2018  3:02AM' > 'Dec  1 2018 12:00AM'
```

which will return `True`

when use cast() function `select cast('Dec  1 2018 12:00AM' as timestamp)` which will give `null`.
Thus, how can we compare the date in the format `mm dd yy 00:00AM`

Comment: I'm not an Impala expert, but I could not see any date function which can parse a partial month name.  So, you might have to do this processing outside your database.

Comment: and what you see when you write `select now()`?

Comment: `select now()` will get the time type 'yy-mm-dd 00:00:00' such as 2018-11-29 21:24:50.815029000

Answer (score 0):

You should use Impala [implicit formating](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html) `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`. In your case you should use for example

```
select cast('2018-11-23 03:02:00.000' as timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unix_timestamp()`.  I think the right format is:

```
select unix_timestamp('Nov 23 2018  3:02AM', 'MMM DD YYYY HH:mmPP')
```

Comment: This will cause error `Bad date/time conversion format: MMM DD YYYY HH:mmPP` and stop working.